# Rails Helper create unintended Array ouput

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have created a rails helper method, So far so good the only problem is it created an unexpected array ouput.

I did try the key value pair using the each method but the array still there.

I'm trying to figure it out how to remove the unexpected array

My `application_helper.rb`

```rb
def bid_items(origin, destination)
        item = Item.where(item_deliver_from: origin).where(item_deliver_to: destination).where(shopper_id: current_user)
end
```

My `search_results.html.rb`

```rb
<%= bid_items(trip.origin, trip.destination).each do |item| %>
    <div class="card border-0">
        <%= image_tag item.cover_image_url(:cover_image_medium), class: "card-img-top" %>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title"><%= item.name %></h5>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Though I got the intended results still, there's an unexpected array 
check the image 
I just want to remove this area

[See Red X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4MW2.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `=` sign from `<%= bid_items(trip.origin, trip.destination).each do |item| %>`

So, make it `<% bid_items(trip.origin, trip.destination).each do |item| %>`

Comment: Thanks, Man did not see that :D

Comment: This question has been literally asked dozens of times already on [so]. Answering it only fragments the knowledge, the better reaction would be to close as a duplicate.